# Multiple styles in one UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

What's the best way to combine multiple styles into one UITableView?

For instance, in the iTunes Music Store App (Music tab), there's ads on top, then large rounded table cells, and then Grouped-styled table cells, etc.  I'm looking to have a custom view cell on top, then several rows of Grouped-style table cells, and then several rows of Plain-styled table cells.

I'm currently initializing my UITableView with UITableViewStyleGrouped, which works well for my need of Grouped-style cells, but I can't find a good way of overwriting the individual cells' styles so that I can create the other styled cells.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The iTunes Store view is probably all a single UITableViewStyleGrouped with a few sections, a header (ads) and footer (terms and conditions). If that's the look you're going for that's all you need. Where do you see the plain styled cells?

Comment: Yeah, you're right - there's no plain-styled cells in the iTunes Store.  But I'm looking use them in what I'm building.  Is it possible to have both Grouped-styled and Plain-styled in the same table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about the table style (one has cells that are full width of the view. Other has lines background and rounded corners on sections).

You could probably hack something together by using a scroll view and 2 embedded table views with their scrolling disabled, but I wouldn't recommend it. You're not supposed to put table views in scroll views and it won't be very Appley and HIGy - prepare yourself for headaches.

You might want to consider rethinking your view structure.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to think the same thing. I was trying my best to match a design, but now I think I'll just have to alter it and make everything grouped-based. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:  You can set `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` properties to custom views to get most of the way towards the iTunes Music Store app screen you're talking about. The rest is just returning different `UITableViewCell` types depending on which section you're in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        // return a cell with the first section's style
        break;
    case 1:
        // return a cell with the second section's style
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this create any conflict with cell reuse? Can dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier still be used if I have to return a new cell each time this method is called?

Comment: Yes, you still use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`' just use a different identifier for each type of cell.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. But I'm not sure that my issue is with `UITableViewCellStyle` so much as with `UITableViewStyle`. It seems that the styling associated with a plain-style and a grouped-style cell is done at the table view level, not cell level, correct?  Or is there a way to have one section of an UITableView be styled with `UITableViewStylePlain` and another section be styled with `UITableViewGrouped`?

Comment: No. Plain v. grouped is set up for the entire table view. Analyzing the iTunes Music Store app, you have a custom headerView with four 'featured' graphics, then section 0, which uses a (custom) table view cell that has thumbnail art on the left, artist, title and rating next to the artwork, and a disclosure chevron. Then in section 1 you have plain table view cells. ("Complete my album", "Redeem") with disclosure chevron, and plain cells in section 2, too ("Apple ID:") with no disclosure.